# mysql cursor and count number of loops. how to count number of loops in mysql cursor

Tags: mysql

How can i count number of loops in cursor

```
declare counter int;

set counter := 1;
    open cursor1;                           
    LOOP1: loop      

set counter := counter + 1; 

    end loop LOOP1;
```

but i get error of:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set counter := counter + 1; 

    end loop LOOP1;
```

Comment: What you posted (removing the cursor line) wrapped in a procedure "compiles" ok and is callable (infinite loop). Please post your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to remove  the `:` in the `set` to solve the sql syntax error:

```
set counter = 1;
```

and

```
set counter = counter + 1;
```